# highcharts Bars should start beginning at the line

Tags: highcharts

[image]

how can i  start Bars at beginning of the line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following and its working.

```
"plotOptions": {
        "bar": {
            "pointPlacement": -0.2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start bar on the tick you need to increase the **tickWidth**, which is set to 0 by default for the category axes and set the **tickmarkPlacement to 'on'**.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6j80sL75/

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', ...],
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickWidth